Maximum cpu usage of app service plan is showing null with powershell or bash script, but showing value in the azure portal
Maximum cpu usage of app service plan is showing null with powershell or bash script, but showing maximum values in the azure portal, need help to get metrics of cpu percentage maximum value using bash or powershell scritp.

I encountered a similar issue where the maximum CPU usage metric for an Azure App Service Plan was showing as null when using PowerShell or Bash script, but the Azure Portal displayed the metric correctly. After some troubleshooting, I was able to retrieve the correct maximum CPU usage value using PowerShell. Here’s the step-by-step solution that worked for me:
Use the Get-AzMetric cmdlet from the Azure PowerShell module to fetch the CPU usage metric. Ensure you have the right permissions and that your Azure PowerShell context is set to the correct subscription.
$resourceId = "/subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourceGroups/<resource-group-name>/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/<app-service-plan-name>"
$metricData = Get-AzMetric -ResourceId $resourceId -MetricName "CpuPercentage" -TimeGrain "00:01:00" -StartTime (Get-Date).AddDays(-1) -EndTime (Get-Date) -AggregationType "Maximum"

Replace <subscription-id>, <resource-group-name>, and <app-service-plan-name> with your actual values.
If the $metricData object contains data, check for non-null maximum values and format the output as a table to review the results:
$metricData.Data | Where-Object { $_.Maximum -ne $null } | Format-Table TimeStamp, Maximum


The output will display timestamps alongside the corresponding maximum CPU percentages, confirming that the metrics are being fetched correctly.
In my case, the maximum CPU usage value was 12%, as shown in the following output:

References:

Monitor apps in Azure App Service - Understand metrics
Get-AzMetric

